# Proof $ \nabla \cdot ( \nabla g \times \vec{F}) = - \nabla \cdot (g \nabla \times \vec{F})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How does one tackle the following proof

$$\nabla \cdot ( \nabla g \times \vec{F}) = - \nabla \cdot (g \nabla \times \vec{F}) $$

I tried using the following identity :

$ \nabla \cdot ( \vec{F} \times \vec{G} ) = (\nabla \times \vec{F}) \cdot \vec{G} -  (\nabla \times \vec{G}) \cdot \vec{F}$

But things went wrong. Could someone assist

Comment: what did you get when you applied the vector identity?

Answer (score 1):

For the RHS, you should get
$$-\nabla g \cdot \mathrm{curl} \ F - g \mathrm{div}(\mathrm{curl} \ F) = -\nabla g\cdot\mathrm{curl} \ F.$$

Using the identity you give, the LHS is
$$(\mathrm{curl} \ \nabla g)\cdot F - (\mathrm{curl} \ F)\cdot\nabla g = -(\mathrm{curl} \ F)\cdot\nabla g,$$
since $\mathrm{curl} \ \nabla f = 0$ for any $f$.